# Want to convert the b2b app to regular app

Tags: ios, app-store, b2b, apple-developer-account

I have developed an iPad App. Now the application is live as B2B app. Now my client wants to convert the app into a regular app or normal app on the app store. how we convert the b2b app to normal app
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply go into AppStore Connect and select one of the non-B2B options in *Pricing and Avalability*

[image]